# Several functions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do two functions here, one where I use addition and one where i use multiplication. If i were to type in 5 and 6 the calculate button would generate 11 and 30. Should i put the multiplication function in this one, or a separate one? And if so, how do i connect it to that one button?

```js
function calculate() {
  tal1 = document.getElementById("tal1").value;
  tal2 = document.getElementById("tal2").value;
  var answer;
  answer = tal1 * 1 + tal2 * 1;
  document.getElementById("answer").value = answer;
}
```

```html
<form id="f1" name="f1">
  <input id="tal1" type="text"><br><br>
  <input id="tal2" type="text"><br><br>
  <input onclick="calculate()" type="button" value="Calculate!"><br><br>
  <input id="answer" type="text"><br><br>
  <input id="answer" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: id's must be unique, you cannot use "answer" twice. So where would you put the second answer?

Comment: You should use `answer1` and `answer2` accordingly, you cannot have more than one element with the same id in a page.

Comment: Technically the multiplication belongs in its own function. But that also involves using `addEventListener` instead of `onclick=calculate()` so you can add more than one function to the button. `onclick=` syntax only allows for one function to be connected to an element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a single function for calculating both values.

- Use declared variables on top,
- take [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) for converting string to number
- use [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) for string who are converted to `NaN` with value zero, have a look to [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values, too,
- take unique `id` for addressing an element,
- assign the calculation to the result elements,
- take a [`<button>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) with an event for calculation and `type="button"`, otherwise the button works as submit.

```js
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function multiply(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function calculate() {
    var tal1 = +document.getElementById("tal1").value || 0,
        tal2 = +document.getElementById("tal2").value || 0;
        //     ^ unary plus, get a number
        //                                            ^^^^ check for truthyness, take
        //                                                 zero if the first operand
        //                                                 is falsy, like NaN

    document.getElementById("sum").value = add(tal1, tal2);
    document.getElementById("product").value = multiply(tal1, tal2);
}
```

```html
<form id="f1" name="f1">
    <input id="tal1" type="text"><br><br>
    <input id="tal2" type="text"><br><br>
    <button onclick="calculate();" type="button">Calculate!</button><br><br>
    <input id="sum" type="text"><br><br>
    <input id="product" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: But i want to use three separate functions. One for the addition, one for the multiplication and one for the answer. If that makes sense?

Comment: which parameters do you want for the addition/multiplication functions? just values or is or the reference to the input?

Comment: The input. So like: 
2 
3 
"Calculate"
5
6.

Comment: Exactly like that! Thanks alot Nina!

Comment: And if i would like to calculate the sum of the two previous answers without adding an extra function?

Comment: you could use `document.getElementById("total").value = add(add(tal1, tal2), multiply(tal1, tal2));` as a nested approach with the two functions.